# Health monitoring solution from inside of virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

I'm taking a part in developing some application which will run on a virtualized platform, currently it's going to be on VMware ESXi but I would not exclude the KVM option.

The application is real-time and going to be very sensitive to resource shortage, especially to CPU and network bandwidth. Because of this extreme sensitivity we need some health monitoring mechanism that will be able to gather statistics about the system resources provided to a specific virtual machine with our application running inside. It may have a feature to record collected statistics to a log file or send alarms. It’s not a problem to collect such data from the host (hypervisor) level, but the application running inside the VM hasn’t got the required permissions, so cannot access ESXi API as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is enough information here for us to help you. What guest operating system(s) do you need this monitoring data from? Would you have privileged (root/administrator) access inside those guests?

There are plenty of way to collect resource utilization data (top,sar,wmic,powershell) inside various operating systems, and still more ways to make that data readable or push it to another host, so your question seems incomplete or just vague, sorry.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer.
The guest OS is customized distribution of CentOS 5.3
Yes, I have "root" privileges inside of guest OS.
I need to collect data about current resource allocation from host level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at collecting host/hypervisor-layer information from within a running guest, then one possible approach may be to collect "drop files" (containing the running hypervisor statistics) from the hypervisor/host at the guest. It's delayed-timed at best, but still better than not having the context of the current hypervisor/host state.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is install vSphere SDK for Perl in that VM and use it to pull statistics from the vCenter.